# ¿Como puedo filtrar un array por una key especifica en php?

Tags: php

Cordial saludo

La presente es para manifestar una duda técnica al respecto, lo que sucede es que tengo un array que estoy llenando con un foreach, pero este se encuentra directamente con un nivel de indices 0, 1, 2 y adentro ya tengo los indices que necesito en cada uno de estos, lo que necesito es filtrar ese array solamente por el indice asociativo llamado "dato", pero no se como realizarlo hasta el momento.

```
  $heads = ['Orden', 'usuario', 'Fecha de nacimiento', 'Sexo'];
  foreach ($heads as $key => $value) {
   $array[$key] = ["dato" => $value] ;
    }
  print_r($array);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solo quiero traer los indices dato con su respectivo valor

Comment: Buenas, me cuesta entender lo que quieres hacer. Podrías colocar un ejemplo mínimo de como es la entrada que recibes o generas y como debería ser la salida ?
Ese array de la imagen es tu entrada?

Comment: Esa imagen es tu array de entrada? Como es el resultado que esperas obtener?

Comment: por favor reformula tu pregunta ó da mas detalle de tu código, revisa la pagina: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour